# Right stack for developing native real time sound app for android

Tags: android, angularjs, reactjs, android-ndk, native

I want to make a decision about choosing a stack of programming languages and frameworks to develop my android app.

I am familiar with pretty much the most popular frameworks today on the web including react and redux, angular, JavaScript. I'm also familiar with Java android and C/C++.

My question is, for real time purposes such as sound processing and manipulation, do I have enough tools for starting to develop the app with react/angular (react-native/fuse/ionic etc) or should I still go with the android NDK and make my real time processing with a language that is more close to the machine language?

Maybe the right question is can I used them both? Can I mix JavaScript, android Java, and NDK-C++ through jni? JavaScript and Java would be in charge of the UI and C++ part can process the real time things?

On one hand I feel that web developing frameworks are more familiar for me, but on the other hand, maybe those frameworks are not compatible to these kinds of apps.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Before getting "too close to the metal" you could build a prototype of the critical part of your app, which seems to be the sound processing. Depending on the algorithms you plan on using, you might get away with a java implementation (android-sdk). If that's the case you can easily use react-native and offload the performance heavy tasks to Java, while doing UI things etc. in javascript.

I had a similar issue, I had to implement a calculation heavy algorithm (dynamic time warping/nearest neighbour classification). I implemented it in multiple languages (js, ruby, php, c++, python), which helped me figure out which way to go (c++). If you implemented the procedure in one language it is mostly copy&paste to get a gist of the performance in other languages.

Comment: I already built a prototype with android-java and the delay times (latency) are horrible, tried few libraries that work with c++ and got much better results. I'm sure that I can do all UI things with java and calculations and processing with c++ on the NDK layer, but I feel more confident with JavaScript, and if that's possible to combine it with C++ NDK (which when I think of it now, it must be possible with JNI). Thanks for the comment.